# Cambie el nombre del repositorio en GitHub ahora no me sube cambios desde mi vscode

Tags: git, github, vscode, línea-de-comandos, push

Tengo un problema cambie el nombre de mi repositorio en GitHub
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] hice algunas actualizaciones desde la carpeta donde tenia mis archivos del repositorio pero me da error. Que comando necesito para ingresar el cambio hecho es decir el nombre del repositorio actual.
Momentáneamente estoy usando `git remote set-url origin new_url`donde en `new-url` pongo mi nueva url pero al pushear aunque me aparece en linea roja la nueva dirección no sube cambios, antes me aparecía la url antigua tambien en rojo.

Me aparece:

```
$ git push
To https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
 ! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind       
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Github te permitirá seguir pusheando con la URL anterior desplegando nada más que una advertencia: `el repositorio se movió, prefiera pushear a la nueva URL xxx`. Así que puedes descartar que ese sea el problema.

Comment: Podrias colocar el comando que estas ejecutando y sa salida para tener una idea del problema?

Comment: tira `git pull` y despues haces `push`

Comment: No es la mejor solución pero siempre puedes clonar de nuevo el repositorio en tu máquina y empezar desde ahí.